# Inserting "marker" instructions into assembly without GCC reordering them

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, inline-assembly

For purposes of doing performance analysis it is useful to be able to
tell which line of C code goes with which line of generated assembly
code. This can be very difficult once a sufficient number of
optimization passes get involved, and I devised the following scheme
to make it easier (though it has a lot of caveats). I figured I would
use in-line assembly to insert an instruction that is effectively a
nop, but that the compiler would rarely or never generate itself. Then
when I looked at the generated code I could infer that assembly code
that appears between the inserted marker instructions probably comes
from C code that lies between the in-line assembly statements.

I came up with these candidates:

```
// Force insertion of a instruction that will only clobber
// flags and that the compiler hardly ever uses itself. Lie and say
// that it alters memory to try to prevent the compiler from moving
// around. Mark it volatile so the compiler can't remove it entirely.
#define ASSEMBLY_MARKER_0()                 \
    __asm__ volatile ("cld" : /* no outputs */ : /* no inputs */ : "memory", "cc")

#define ASSEMBLY_MARKER_1()                 \
    __asm__ volatile ("xorl %%eax,0" : /* no outputs */ : /* no inputs */ : "memory", "cc")
```

Then I decided to test whether the compiler would move instructions
across these boundaries. clang appears to do exactly what I want, but
GCC appears to not be deterred either by the memory clobbering or the
fact that this snippet is volatile. It reorders instructions anyway!
Is there any way to prevent this?

I know there are a lot of caveats to this method even if I get it to
work -- I may heavily influence generated code around the markers. But
I maintain that it would still be useful for finding things like
accidental implicit conversions between integer widths, and other
"wait that should never be necessary..." type problems.

You can see the difference between GCC and clang here: https://godbolt.org/z/ZtUPc9

C code:

```
int f(int x)
{
    __asm__ volatile ("xorl %%eax,0" : /* no outputs */ : /* no inputs */ : "memory", "cc");
    int j = x << 3;
    __asm__ volatile ("xorl %%eax,0" : /* no outputs */ : /* no inputs */ : "memory", "cc");
    return j;
}
```

GCC:

```
    xorl %eax,0
    xorl %eax,0
    lea     eax, [0+rdi*8]
    ret
```

Clang:

```
    xor     dword ptr [0], eax
    lea     eax, [8*rdi]
    xor     dword ptr [0], eax
    ret
```

Edits to answer questions in comments:

**Why not nops?** Because gcc inserts those itself often. The point is to stick out.

**Why not move code into its own function?** If you're doing this analysis on C++ template code for example, there be many layers of inlining that occur before producing the function that actually goes in the executable, and the code may be very different if you turn off the inlining (e.g. the code may have been written with the assumption that constant folding, dead code elimitation etc would get rid of trivial things).

Comment: Iif you are interested in performance then inlining asm instructions will defeat the optimizer from working leaving you with unoptimized code that doesnt perform well.  Just learn to read the asm.

Comment: isolate the code under test to a function, easy to see no markers needed.

Comment: You might think gcc reordered stuff, but you could also say that it optimized `return j` into `return x << 3` and having done that it has simply removed `j` altogether. PS: you want `xorq $0, %%rax"` because what you have is a memory write through a NULL pointer and will crash. Even better something that doesn't change flags either, maybe `leaq (%rax), %rax`.

Comment: I think GCC will annotate the assembly with information about the source line. The regular debugging switch, `-g`, might do that, or there might be another.

Comment: @old_timer: function isolation is what I usually do, but that can change the generated code a lot too. sometimes I'm dealing with 10+ layers of inlining squashed into one giant function, and where the generated code will be wildly different if inlining and resulting constant folding and dead branch elimination don't happen.

Comment: Also, instead of crafting dummy instructions, you can insert `nop` instructions or labels, like `ThisIsMyMarker0:`. Or comment lines. (Labels can be a problem because GCC might generate multiple instances of instruction sequences for one sequence of C source code, and then you would have duplicate labels.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah but on complicated examples those annotations are crazy inaccurate

Comment: @EricPostpischil gcc inserts lots of nops on its own, so it's hard to tell which are yours

Comment: The ideal instruction for that is `nopl foo(%rcx)` where `foo` is some constant.  This is a nop that doesn't doo anything and you can choose the constant freely.  gcc (specifically, gas) only inserts `nopl` instructions with `rax` as the base register, so you can easily tell this apart.  You can even use different base registers for different kinds of nops.

Comment: Trying to do performance analysis correlating source code with generating assembly is very fragile. You could easily conclude some particular C source code is good, but a slight change to the code or a change of compiler version could upset it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm aware. That doesn't mean it's never worthwhile though, just rarely..

Comment: The main problem is that while your asm statement is volatile, the calculations around it are not and unless they have an observable side-effect or ordering requirement, the compiler is free to move them around your volatile statement.  You might get somewhere using an inline function, but I'm not sure if that cuts it.

Comment: @fuz: yes, "It reorders instructions anyway! Is there any way to prevent this?"

Comment: @JosephGarvin In general, not.  You can give strong recommendations to the compiler by making more and more stuff volatile or by making variables input dependencies to your “marker” statement, but you cannot prevent the compiler from evaluating computations earlier than expected.

Comment: GCC manual says: *Note that the compiler can move even volatile asm instructions relative to other code, including across jump instructions. For example, on many targets there is a system register that controls the rounding mode of floating-point operations. Setting it with a volatile asm statement, as in the following PowerPC example, does not work reliably....To make it work as expected, add an artificial dependency to the asm by referencing a variable in the subsequent code* https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html ("=X")

Comment: Why don't you disable optimization at all by `-O0`?

Comment: @thebusybee: because the OP wants to see where instructions in the *optimized* compiler output are coming from, and backtrack from inefficiencies that still exist after optimization to eliminate them.  Not to look at braindead useless code with no inlining.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, understood. How about asking `objdump` to generate an augmented disassembly?

Comment: @thebusybee: That can break down after heavy inlining, optimization, and auto-vectorization.  They already know about https://godbolt.org/ which uses the same debug info in an even more useful way: mouseover asm to show the corresponding source line.  And color highlighting to match asm to source when possible.  I'm not convinced that `asm volatile` can help much here; maybe just for getting in the right ballpark before spending time and brainpower on figuring out the source->asm logic.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I decided to test whether the compiler would move instructions across these boundaries. clang appears to do exactly what I want, but GCC appears to not be deterred either by the memory clobbering or the fact that this snippet is volatile. It reorders instructions anyway! Is there any way to prevent this?

Not really.  The point is that such memory barriers avoid reordering stuff across it that is *volatile* (like volatile accesses or asm volatile) and / or memory accesses.    Or in the case of x86 and cc (condition code) parts of def-use chains of condition code cannot be moved across.  Such barriers do not whatsoever avoid moving unrelated instructions across it.

Sometimes it can be helpful to add options `-save-temps -fverbose-asm` to better understand assembly code and its relation to C. New versions of GCC dump C/C++ code alongside assembly code (dumped as *.s).  When you inspect assembly (as opposed to disassembly) it's sufficient to inject asm comments to show where the inline asm is injected, there is no need to add actual instructions.  Legibility of assembly might be improved by disabling debug-info (`-g0`).

To better understand the code, you can also disable passes that usually result in great amount of instruction reordering like instruction scheduling (`-fno-schedule-insns`,
`-fno-schedule-insns2`) but that has a big performance impact, of course.